# How to remove a tag from deleted files in CVS?

Tags: tags, cvs

I am trying to maintain a system of tags for my CVS data. One set of tags contains unique tags that never change. They are the nightly-regressed tags. The another type of tag is a  single tag that keep on moving. This is the nightly regress-candidate tag. So, This tag keeps on moving from one version to a newer one for a file. Lets call this tag 'regress_this'. At the time of regression my intention is to checkout this particular tag and run my regression.

My problem is that checking this tag out brings back deleted files too. Since over the course of a day some files get deleted that had the 'regress-this' tag from before. If I can automate that removing a file from CVS will also remove any specific tag on the file then my problem will be solved.

The CVS cvs gets to this the 'rtag -a' but this is not what I am looking for because it also applies the tag to the head revision of all the other files. Also, I dont have a clear-cut list of files that were removed.

The way I apply the tag is by running 'cvs tag -F tagname filenames' so only a few files get tagged at a  time.

I need to filter out the deleted files from my movable tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [removing the tag](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/manual/cvs-1.12.13/cvs_4.html#SEC53) from the repository before applying it:

```
cvs rtag -d regress_this
```